# How to replace string with int in button action?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, filereader

I have in button action this code:

```
String text = jTextField18.getText();
int x = Integer.parseInt(text);

String text = jTextField18.getText();
int x = Integer.parseInt(text);
try {
    FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("Name.txt");
    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
    String str = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        str = br1.readLine();
    }
    br1.close();

    jTextField13.setText(str);
```

But when I press the button `jTextField13` is `""` without any text. Why?

Comment: Change `str=br1.readLine();` to `str += br1.readLine() + " ";`

Comment: nope it is still doesn't work

Comment: OK, then you will want to create and post your [mcve], a small compilable and runnable program, that we can test and modify, so we can actually see what is not working and why. This would offer your best chance of getting a decent answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code

```
FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("Name.txt");
BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
String str = null;
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    str = br1.readLine();
}
br1.close();
```

opens the text file, reads it line by line, but keeps only the last line.
If this line is empty, str will be empty as well.

Instead, you could

- either do

  ```
  String str = "";
  for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
      str += br1.readLine() + "\n";
  }
  br1.close();
  ```
- or just rely on streams (on Java 8):

  ```
  String str = br1.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
  br1.close();
  ```

Note: Besides that, you could use try-with-resources:

```
try (
     FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("Name.txt");
     BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1)) {
    // stuff above
}
```

If that still doesn't change anything, you could add debugging output during the loop resp. after the assignment of `str`.